# Delete from oracle db with oledb in vb

Tags: vb.net, oracle

i got a problem deleting rows in Oracle database using oledb commands

```
dim conn_str as string = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=ORACLE;User Id=Test;Password=Test;"    
Sql = "delete from rezervacija_test p where p.datum < (select max(datum) from rezervacija_test) "
    Dim conection As New OleDbConnection(conn_str)
    conection.Open()
    Dim Cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql, conection)
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conection.Close()
```

This code dont gives any error but after it is executed there ar no changes in my database.
If i simply copy the sql query and execute it with plsql it works.
Can anyone tell me am i mistaking somewhere or ?

Eaven tried like this

```
delete from rezervacija_test p where p.datum < '03-jan-2017'"
```

But still nothing

Comment: What is the data type of column `datum`?

Comment: Its date type, Datum in macedonian means date.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery() returns the #rows affected.  Check that.

Answer (score 0):

FOr other people with the same problem, i just removed the alias for the table and now it works. Strange i know but it was the problem in my case